# Trouble downloading Pandas, python3 on macOS

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I just downloaded python 3.6 after using python 2 for awhile. I need to download my modules for python 3. I started with downloading pandas (unsuccessfully) and I have tried running in my terminal:

```
$ sudo pip3 install --user pandas

$ pip3 install --user pandas

$ sudo pip3 install pandas

$ pip3 install pandas
```

I also ran a few more variations trying to play with it. I receive this error at the end of the output for that last attempt:

```
    Collecting pandas
    Using cached pandas-0.19.2.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:749) -- Some packages may not be found!
    Couldn't find index page for 'numpy' (maybe misspelled?)
    Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:749) -- Some packages may not be found!
    No local packages or working download links found for numpy>=1.7.0
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/68/xjx6zfr570199v_w0dhd9y3c0000gn/T/pip-build-v90_t75r/pandas/setup.py", line 696, in <module>
        **setuptools_kwargs)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/distutils/core.py", line 108, in setup
        _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 315, in __init__
        self.fetch_build_eggs(attrs['setup_requires'])
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 361, in fetch_build_eggs
        replace_conflicting=True,
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 850, in resolve
        dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(req, ws, installer)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1122, in best_match
        return self.obtain(req, installer)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1134, in obtain
        return installer(requirement)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 429, in fetch_build_egg
        return cmd.easy_install(req)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 659, in easy_install
        raise DistutilsError(msg)
    distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('numpy>=1.7.0')

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/68/xjx6zfr570199v_w0dhd9y3c0000gn/T/pip-build-v90_t75r/pandas/
```

I am pretty new to python in general so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: can you do pip3 -V in console

Comment: I would strongly recommend you to download Anaconda 4.2 (Python 3.5) for OSX: https://www.continuum.io/downloads#osx

Comment: Result: $ pip3 -V
pip 9.0.1 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages (python 3.6)

Comment: I downloaded Anaconda and seems to be working well using the conda installer. Thanks!